# I want to pass a parameter isloggedin user to the django frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am passing a list of user objects to the frontend. The frontend wants to display currently logged in users' information seperately and other users info seperately.For that I want to pass one extra field in the users serializer. I am using viewsets and serializers to pass a list of users to the django frontend.How do i do it.

My serializer looks like

```
class SomeUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for `some_user` table
    """
    isLogedInUser = serializers.SerializerMethodField('is_logged_in_user')
    user = UserSerializer(many=False)

    def is_logged_in_user(self, request):
        return self.user==request.user

    class Meta:
        model = SomeUser
        fields = ('user', 'something', 'isLogedInUser')
```

Something is wrong with my is_logged_in_user method. It should be returning true or false flag along with the user object depending on whether or not it is a curently logged in user

Comment: I am using serializers and viewsets not forms and templates

Comment: "Something is wrong" is not a problem description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serializer method used by `isLogedInUser` is taking an argument called `request`. However, according to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), the method is called with the object being serialized, an instance of `SomeUser`.

You need to change the argument and get the request via [additional context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context), like this:

```py
    class SomeUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        """
        Serializer for `some_user` table
        """
        isLogedInUser = serializers.SerializerMethodField('is_logged_in_user', context={'request': request})
        user = UserSerializer(many=False)

        def is_logged_in_user(self, obj):
            return obj.user == self.context['request'].user

        class Meta:
            model = SomeUser
            fields = ('user', 'something', 'isLogedInUser')
```

Comment: It worked for me with slight modifications. I didnt pass 'context={'request': request}' while calling serializers.SerializerMethodField()